# How to make different interface for each strategy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have following situation.

I make ad rotation and I want to have a few strategies. But how to do it, when different strategies needs different params?

e.g.:

LeastShowedStrategy needs only collection of ads

but

UserRelevantStrategy needs both collection of ads and user

Is there some way how to do it clean or should I give up doing this with Strategy Pattern?

update: 
There are a few lines of code, i wrote. I do not know, how to parametrize Strategy, when every strategy has different needs.

```
class MyEngine::AdsHelper
    def get_ad
        ads = get_all_possible
        Engine.strategy.get_next(ads)
    end
end

class MyEngine::Engine
    attr_accessor :strategy
end
```

initializer:

```
MyEngine::Engine.strategy = MyEngine::Strategies::ConcreteStrategy.new
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail, your question is not very clear...

Answer (score 0):

Given that the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is based around using a single interface with multiple concrete implementations, I am not quite sure what you are attempting to accomplish here.  My initial hunch off the information provided is that your needs don't really match the strategy pattern but would need to know more about what you are actually trying to accomplish to provide alternatives.

### Strategy Pattern overview pseudo-code

```
interface ITaxStrategy:
    decimal CalculateTax (decimal Subtotal)

public class NYTaxStrategy : ITaxStrategy

    CalculateTax(decimal Subtotal)
    {
       return Subtotal * 0.08125;
    }

public class UKTaxStrategy: ITaxStrategy

    CalculateTax(decimal Subtotal)
    {
       return (Subtotal * 0.825) + VAT;
    }
```

The above allows you to inject any particular *TaxStrategy* implementation into an object that needs it using a builder, factory, DI Framework or similar mechanism but requires a consistent interface / abstract class to define the strategy contract.

Hope that helps...